# UITableView animated resizing issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, autoresizingmask

I have UIViewController **A** with the embedded UIViewController **B** without constraints (I need just autoresizing mask). **B** contains UITableView with edges constraints.

When I change the height of the embedded **B**-ViewController.view in animation block, an animation plays right

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
            self.contentView.frame.size = .init(width: self.contentView.frame.width, height: 200)
            self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

But the table "cuts" its cells to the final state. How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: What constraints have you put on the UITableView, and what were you expecting the cells to look like in the final state?

Comment: What is the numberOfRowsInSection before animation?